# How do I decrypt a hex string using blowfish in C#?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, blowfish

So I've been given a task to prove that it's possible to decrypt a string represented in hex bytes that has been encrypted using Blowfish using C#.

Here's what have:

- An encrypted string represented in hex-bytes.
- An encryption key as a string.

Now perhaps I'm a little naive but I thought that this process would be simple.

i.e. grab a Blowfish implementation off the net and then simple plug in the encryption key and encrypted text and it would output the string in a readable format.

Unfortunately this doesn't appear to be the case. Over the last few hours I've tried a couple of different libraries out but settled on BouncyCastle as it appears to be the most popular.  However there isn't much documentation (noted in other questions here and other sites) and I really don't have a clue about how to get this done.

Here's what I have:

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;


public class CryptTest
{
    public void Decrypt()
    {           
        var engine = new BlowfishEngine();
        var param = new KeyParameter(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("sdjerwioukjiefdjewiujewiunjeuwer"));
        var input = Hex.Decode("db247cceae61fddbcbb62d00281e0446");

        BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new BufferedBlockCipher(engine);

        cipher.Init(false, param);

        byte[] outBytes = new byte[input.Length];

        int len1 = cipher.ProcessBytes(input, 0, input.Length, outBytes, 0);

        cipher.DoFinal(outBytes, len1);

        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(outBytes));
    }

}
```

I've tried to adapt this from the Test class that comes with BouncyCastle.  Can anyone point me in the direction of a good example that does what I want to do?

I think at least one of the problems I'm having is with the key - it doesn't look like it is in hex format but I don't know what to do with it.

UPDATE:

I've also tried a different library from [here](https://www.schneier.com/code/blowfish.cs) because it looks closer to what I want to do.

i.e.

```
BlowFish b = new BlowFish(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("sdjerwioukjiefdjewiujewiunjeuwer"));

var result1 = b.Decrypt_CBC("db247cceae61fddbcbb62d00281e0446");
var result2 = b.Decrypt_ECB("db247cceae61fddbcbb62d00281e0446");

Console.WriteLine(result1 + "\n" + result2);
```

But I'm still getting gibberish returned.

UPDATE 2:

Ended up going with something simpler for the time being.  The (apparent) lack of documentation with Bouncy Castle makes it extremely difficult for those that have limited experience/understanding of encryption to use it properly.  However we will likely want to get this going in the future, so I'm still interested if someone can point me the right direction.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Basically it's not decrypting the string and I don't know where to begin to figure out why.

Comment: SO what **does** happen? Does it explode?

Comment: No, it just outputs something that is unreadable.

Comment: Then something doesn't match between your encryption and your decryption.  Check your IV.

Comment: Will do. Every code example I've seen has the key as a hex string and the key I've been given isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You're ignoring the decryption of the first chunk (from `ProcessBytes()`).

<strike>Instead of using cipher objects directly, you should use `CryptoStream`:</strike>

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(new CryptoStream(new MemoryStream(input), cipher, CrytoStreamMode.Read))
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

BouncyCastle does not implement `ICryptoTransform`, so you need to concatenate the result of each call yourself.